# IAR LINKER Exported symbols with block sections

Tags: linker, embedded, block, memory-address, iar

I am using IAR linker and I need to define exported symbols of start/end address of my defined blocks in linker file:

**Example**:

I defined my block like this:

```
define block AppFlash with fixed order, alignment = 32
{
   block App_1,
   block App_2,
   block App_3,
};
```

And now I need to get the start address of the blocks, by using  `__section_begin("App_1")`, etc.

The problem that I have is that I only am able to retrieve this info at runtime, but not at startup, and I have assembler files that need some start address references of the linker for vector table configuring...

Explanation:

C code Files:
`result = __section_begin("App_1")` -> Runs fine, info retrieved is the expected

Assembler files:
`EXTERN MAINSTACK_START` -->> I cant make a define with the `__Section_begin` function in the same way

Is there any way to define a exported symbol with the start address of a block in IAR linker file?

I know it's possible with regions, but I dont know how to do this with blocks.

Answer (score 1):

In assembler you can use the operators `SFB`, `SFE`, and `SIZEOF` to get the start, end, and length of a block. They are used as in the example below. Note that the block you want to find must be declared before the operators are used.

```
        ;; Forward declaration of section App_1
        SECTION App_1:DATA:NOALLOC:NOROOT(0)

        PUBLIC begin, beginsym
        PUBLIC end, endsym
        PUBLIC size, sizesym

        SECTION `.text`:CODE:NOROOT(2)
        THUMB

begin:  LDR R0, =SFB(App_1)
        BX LR

end:    LDR R0, =SFE(App_1)
        BX LR

size:   LDR R0, =SIZEOF(App_1)
        BX LR

        SECTION `.data`:DATA:NOROOT(2)
        DATA

beginsym:
        DC32 SFB(App_1)

endsym:
        DC32 SFE(App_1)

sizesym:
        DC32 SIZEOF(App_1)
        
        END
```